# Bash v5.1.4 on Debian question with functions

Tags: bash, heredoc

```
#!/bin/bash

create_function() {
        echo "use root"
        mysql --user=root --password new_db << MY_QUERY
        SHOW tables
}

create_function
```

---

```
jamie@vultr:~/mysql_bash$ sh create_db.sh
create_db.sh: 10: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")
jamie@vultr:~/mysql_bash$
```

Comment: For something this short, I wouldn't bother with a here document. `mysql --user=root --password new_db -e 'SHOW tables'`.

Comment: Or use a here-string: `mysql --user=root --password new_db <<< 'SHOW tables'`

Answer (score 2):

You missed the closing here-doc:

```
    mysql --user=root --password new_db << MY_QUERY
    SHOW tables
MY_QUERY
```